# Inspecting functional keras model structure

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I would like to inspect the layers and connections in a model, after having created a model using the Functional API in Keras. Essentially to start at the output and recursively enumerate the inputs of each layer instance. Is there a way to do this in the Keras or TensorFlow API?

The purpose is to create a more detailed visualisation than the ones provided by Keras (tf.keras.utils.plot_model). The model is generated procedurally based on a parameter file.

I have successfully used attributes of the `KerasTensor` objects to do this inspection:

```
output = Dense(1)(...)

print(output)
print(output.node)
print(output.node.keras_inputs)
print(output.node.keras_inputs[0].node)
```

This wasn't available in TF 2.6, only 2.7, and I realise it's not documented anywhere.

Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: Hi ! You can use netron webapp/plot_model/model.summary() see neural network architecture. https://netron.app/. https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/models_and_layers#model_summary

Comment: netron achieves what I wanted to, inspecting the model, by implementing a parser for the model file format (pb). The visualisation doesn't work for me, but it's good to know about this approach. It's a bit too heavy for me to implement or copy. (and I already mentioned plot_model in the question)